# Display the link with the real server address instead of a misleading one

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, external-links, short-links

In *chat.stackoverflow.com*, I sent the address of a Web page:

*http://www.livraison.simplymarket.fr/achat-en-ligne-preparations-gateaux,91,751,3331.htm?PRO_STEPVENTE=1&idR=91&idS=751&idF=3331&index=*

[In the conversation, a link is made automagically.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/23212201#23212201) But the link shows an incorrect server address: *livraison.simplymarket.fr*. This is misleading. In this case, please show the true server address, here *[www.livraison.simplymarket.fr](http://www.livraison.simplymarket.fr)*. Thank you.

*Addition:*

The lack of *www* alters the server address into a different one. In the general case, the altered address does not work. For example, [*www.moncompteformation.gouv.fr*](http://www.moncompteformation.gouv.fr) works but [*moncompteformation.gouv.fr*](http://moncompteformation.gouv.fr) does not work. The altered address may also work but lead to a different Web site, controlled by another person. This is a security issue.

Comment: How exactly is the lack of www misleading?  What difference does it make?

Comment: It has suspensive points at the end `http://examples.org/...`

Comment: @Braiam — Yes, the link has suspension points at the end, but not at the beginning.

Comment: @Daedalus — The lack of *www* alters the server address into a different one. In the general case, the altered address does not work. For example, *[www.moncompteformation.gouv.fr](http://www.moncompteformation.gouv.fr)* works but *[moncompteformation.gouv.fr](http://moncompteformation.gouv.fr)* does not work. The altered address may also work but lead to a different Web site, controlled by another person. This is a security issue.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Edit your question with that information; it's most certainly relevant to the question, and without that information, there isn't much reason to change this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this is a bug, it is most certainly by design.

There is really not much difference between the two links you show in your example.

In chat, if you wish to have a custom link as opposed to automagic, then you can explicitly create the link using

```
[link text](target url)
```

Note that the url must include `http://`